# why does mysql timediff function give wrong output?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.5

mysql is not giving expected output when i use timediff function. The version of mysql is 5.5

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF( '2018-06-18 08:20:00','2019-01-25 14:29:00'),'%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Like whole result of this query should be what?

Comment: My first point is the diff between two dates is not 838 and i need output in format
09:03:03

Comment: I even tried 
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF( minute,'2019-01-25 14:29:00', '2018-06-18 08:20:00')),'%H:%i:%s');

Comment: `TIMEDIFF` returns a `TIME`. Why are you calling `SEC_TO_TIME` on that result?

Comment: even if i didn't call SEC_TO_TIME  It is giving same result.

Comment: I dont understand what is your expected result. Explain please. Do you want to display total hours,minutes, seconds between these 2 dates? Do you want to display remaining hours,minutes,seconds between dates? As this is difference between these 2 dates:
221 days can be converted to one of these units:

19 094 400 seconds
318 240 minutes
5304 hours
221 days
31 weeks and 4 days

Comment: I want to display total hours:minutes:seconds between these 2 dates.

Comment: The maximum number of hours available in the representation of time is 838 hours. I wish MySQL would *error* when asked to produce out of range values rather than clamping but there you go. I think you'll have to compute the day differences separately and use int/string formatting to construct your result, rather than relying on using `TIME`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIMEDIFF` can't have more than 839 hours and hence, you won't be able to measure the difference for longer ranges than ~35 days. In this case, you can do the following:

- Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to get the seconds
- Convert seconds into `hh:m:ss`

E.g.

```
SET @seconds := (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, '2018-06-18 08:20:00','2019-01-25 14:29:00'));
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(@seconds/3600),':',FLOOR((@seconds%3600)/60),':',(@seconds%3600)%60) AS difference;
```

If you want to do both in the same query then you can use the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, '2018-06-18 08:20:00','2019-01-25 14:29:00')/3600),
':',FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, '2018-06-18 08:20:00','2019-01-25 14:29:00')%3600)/60),
':',(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, '2018-06-18 08:20:00','2019-01-25 14:29:00')%3600)%60) 
AS difference;
```

Here are **[SQLFiddle1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2778d/6/0)** and **[SQLFiddle2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aa76/21/0)**.

Comment: But difference between two dates is not 838 hours. Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for your help. if minutes and seconds are less than 10 it should give two digit like 01,01,10 etc..

Comment: @DineshReddyKancharla you could use `LPAD` for this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a limit to TIMEDIFF, and TIME.
This gives problems when the difference between two TIMESTAMP's gets to big.

But if one calculates the TIMEDIFF between the TIME parts of the TIMESTAMP's, then it's fine.  For the minutes and seconds anyway.

The difference in hours between 2 timestamps can be calculated via TIMESTAMPDIFF.

So the query below concatinates the hour difference (f.e. '5310') to the useful piece of time difference (f.e. ':09:10')

**Example snippet:**

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ts1, ts2), RIGHT(TIMEDIFF(CAST(ts1 AS TIME), CAST(ts2 AS TIME)), 6)) as tm
FROM (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2018-06-18 08:20:00') ts1, TIMESTAMP('2019-01-25 14:29:10') ts2
  union all
  SELECT TIMESTAMP('2019-01-25 14:29:10') ts1, TIMESTAMP('2018-06-18 08:20:00') ts2
) q;
```

**Returns**

```
tm
-------------
5310:09:10 
-5310:09:10
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54a864ad7ca95133fd7337570c2905ed)*

Answer (score 0):

As expected result is: total hours minutes seconds, this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2018-06-18 08:20:00', '2019-01-25 14:29:00'), ":", 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '2018-06-18 08:20:00', '2019-01-25 14:29:00'), ":",
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2018-06-18 08:20:00', '2019-01-25 14:29:00'));
```

This will result in:

```
5310:318609:19116540
```

Comment: @Dinesh Reddy Kancharla Is that what you looking for?

Comment: But minute and seconds are greater than 60.